# Is it possible to kill the 2 Harvesters on Thessia?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This is near the beginning of Priority: Thessia. It's the encounter that's just after Outpost Tykis (where you find the M-560 Hydra, aka the weapon that can one-shot a Banshee) and is between you and the entrance to the Temple of Athame.

[image: harvesters]

Is it possible to kill both Harvesters at this point? Should I even try? I noticed that they flew away after the other fighter ship after a while, but I'm wondering if I would get a bonus to War Assets or something if I was able to save the other pilot and/or if I was only able to kill say, one, make a later battle somewhat easier. Or is the event with the pilot completely scripted and unalterable?

Comment: You don't encounter them later on the mission, at least.  I failed to kill either of them (I came close on one, but they flew away before I could finish them off).  I'm not really sure that +1 Gunship would really mean much in terms of War Assets...

Comment: On a different mission on Tuchanka (I forget the name of it though), I found that the Harvesters there flew away after taking a certain amount of damage. This made the scorpion great for killing them, due to the delayed damage. Basically, they'd fly away with 2-3 shots stuck on them, which by then was too late. I haven't been to this mission yet so I can't say if it works here, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @agent86 Hey man, if that pilot was able to outmaneuver 2 Harvesters, I'd say she'd make a *hell of an addition to the team*.

Comment: Hmm, I must have missed the M-560 on my play-through.  That would have been useful.

Comment: @MBraedley It's right on the right hand side after you speak with the asari in the cutscene. One-shots them if the Banshee's close enough, if it's not it takes out a good chunk of health, but either way, it's handy.

Comment: Huh, I had assumed it was required to kill these jerks. They were my first two kills.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just did this today on normal. I killed them both very quick but the pilot still died as the 2nd one exploded so don't think you can save the pilot or maybe i was just a second to late.

I don't think i could have taken them down much faster since I play an infiltrator with maxed Disruptor ammo, Tactical Cloak and Operational Mastery all focusing on max head shot damage. I'm using a Black Widow V with Extended Barrel IV and Enhanced Scope V and this gear:
[image]

Comment: I killed them on Casual, plus a 3rd targetable Harvester, while the gunship still died to a 4th one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I also killed 3 on that part, I didn't see the 4th, might have been because there was something blocking my view right when the ship went down

Comment: Well, that's pretty definitive. Byebye, pilot.

Comment: i took out 4 harvesters, there were no more harvesters but gunship went down!
no way you can save that damn gunship i say.

Comment: You can find upgrades on planets, which you can open by Liara. They contain +5% weapon damage sometimes... They still can't save the gunship. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible. More Harvesters just keep coming no matter how quickly you take them out. I was wondering the same thing, so I sniped the barrier generator before the harvesters even arrived, then I shot the Hydra at the harvesters right away which one shot one and did some damage to the other, and then another harvester came and the pilot immediately crashed within like 5 seconds of arrival. Seems like coming close to taking out both just triggers her death right away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it's incredibly risky due to the Ravangers in the area as well. Talon 5 will always go down whether you dispatch them or not so it's up to you whether to bunker down and wait it out or slug it out with them.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Blood Pack Punnisher level 10 with the barrel mod and killed them, but when you kill one, another one comes and takes its place. I wished I saved that gunship

Answer (score 0):

I got a lvl 53 infiltrator character (imported with lvl 32 from ME2), with max level warp ammo, weapon damage and headshot damage armor mods (almost the same as Blem posted), a lot of weapon damage bonus from Liara, tactical cloak damage bonus, sniper rifle damage mods and a spectre widow which is a very strong sniper rifle. I managed to kill 4 harvesters with it on normal difficulty, but the gunship was still destroyed. I don't think there is a way to save it.

Btw. I found a nuke, or something like that in the previous part of the map, which I supposed to use against the harvesters. I nuked Kai Leng, but he survived... :D (edit: it was the M-560 Hydra you mentioned, which is not nuclear weapon, but similar)